# android Tabs layout error

Tags: java, android, tabs

I am trying to make tabs layout. I am using tutorial code (below) but it doesn't work. LogCat gives this error:

*04-19 19:02:16.297: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(455): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{jusbrz.bakalauras/jusbrz.bakalauras.FilesTabsActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a TabHost whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.tabhost'*

I added new activitys to manifest.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout 
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<TabWidget 
android:id="@+id/tabs"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</TabWidget>
<FrameLayout 
android:id="@+id/tabcontent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
</FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>     
</TabHost>
```

Using this code in main activity:

```
package jusbrz.bakalauras;
import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TabHost;
public class FilesTabsActivity extends TabActivity{
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.files_tabs_layout);

    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
    Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

    // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, AllFilesTabActivity.class);

    // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Visi").setIndicator("Visi").setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
}
}
```

So where might be the problem?

**EDITED**

```
import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class AllFilesTabActivity extends TabActivity{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.all_files_tab_layout);

        }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing tabhost id in layout.update your layout as:

```
<TabHost
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost">
```

Update your class *FilesTabsActivity* :

```
TabHost tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
TabSpec firstTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Visi");
firstTabSpec.setIndicator("Visi").setContent(new Intent(this,AllFilesTabActivity.class));
/** Add tabSpec to the TabHost to display. */
tabHost.addTab(firstTabSpec);
```

AND IF YOU ARE IF YOU ARE ADDING TAB DYNAMICALLY:

```
setContentView(R.layout.files_tabs_layout);
```

Comment: that didn't helped. Error still pops up

Comment: @LTnewbie : clean project using `Projects --> Clean`

Comment: I cleaned the project. Restarted AVD but the problem exists. I am using 2.2 Maybe this is te problem?

Comment: @LTnewbie : no problem with 2.2 just implement it in right way.

Comment: just comment out `setContentView(R.layout.files_tabs_layout);`

Comment: you are adding tabs dynamically?

Comment: ok comment setContentView(R.layout.files_tabs_layout); line and i'm just conforming u have AllFilesTabActivity Activity ?

Comment: commenting did not helped. Null pointer exception poped up. Yes I have it. (above)

Comment: see this example http://www.androidpeople.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/TabBar1.zip

Comment: @LTnewbie : for getTabHost : see this example http://www.haogongju.net/art/1385175

Comment: could you explain me whats the difference between android:id="@+id/..." and android:id because I missed that part and it solved my problem

Comment: android:id="@+id/given_name" is way for create an id with given name with added automatically in R see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/layout-resource.html#idvalue

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use `TabActivity`, you need to use `@android:id/tabhost` as the android ID value of your `TabHost`.

Browsing a few other questions on StackOverflow, it also seems that doing a "Projects --> Clean" and restarting Eclipse might help too.